# Uninstalling/Reinstalling Tiny Tower

Tags: tiny-tower

I have to uninstall Tiny Tower on my phone. When I reinstall the game, will my progress be saved? I don't ever remember giving any information to the game upon installing the game, so it's not like I have an account or anything. If it doesn't restore my old tower, is there a way of getting it back? 
PS I haven't uninstalled it yet, so if there is an answer as to how to download/have the tower somewhere else, that answer would help as well.

Comment: iOS or Android? Might make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As with any other Application, when you uninstall it, all associated files, like game data, saves, etc., are deleted along with it. So no, **all of your saved data will be erased along with the first copy of the game**. Unless, of course you backed up the files. That could simply be done by finding the save's file and sending it to another device, then reinstall the game, and finally put your old save files where you found them the first time. That is pretty general, though. Details, you would have to find out by doing it.